how to show, maximize and focus a window that is minimized to notification area in Gnome/x11/ubuntu24.04
I have this code to find a window by title,and bring it to focus:
winid=$(wmctrl -l | grep $1 | cut -f1 -d' ')
xdotool windowactivate $winid

it works for windows that are hidden by others etc. But if the window is minimized to notification area (Slack for example), I cannot bring it back in any way, tried also:
    # Ensure the window is mapped (visible)
    xdotool windowmap $winid 2>/dev/null
    # Raise the window to the top of the stack
    xdotool windowraise $winid 2>/dev/null
    # Bring the window to the foreground
    xdotool windowactivate $winid 2>/dev/null
    # (Optional) Force refresh with wmctrl
    wmctrl -i -R $winid 2>/dev/null

Does anyone have a way to do this? thanks!
Ubuntu 24.04, x11
